# WPF DisconnectedItem issue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a problem concerning the issue of DisconnectedItem in wpf bindings.

I should say I have a List namely ProvinceList and in each Province I have an ObservableCollection wich is bound to the ItemsSource property of a ListBox.

The issue comes when I call ProvinceList.Clear() when the Visual Studio throws and InvalidCastException exception and when I trace it I see that the cast object is a City is returning DisconnectedItem.

I have no idea what the problem is. any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show some code & xaml binding?

Comment: it doesn't also work for treeview. that's very strange. what is the problem?

Comment: See the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282894/wpf-listbox-virtualization-creates-disconnecteditems).

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you think this void-of-context single line of code answers the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).